# Quick motion detection in opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, motion-detection

I want to detect motion in a quick way before tracking, will absDiff() (or cmpS() ) between 2 frames be sufficient to achieve this or should I consider something more? Pls keep in mind I'm completely new to vision processing and opencv  :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no quick and easy way. The method I'm trying is to build a background image over time, subtract the foreground which would be anything not part of the background and put a roi over the foreground object.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect the specific object's motion, you would need 'connected components' calculation. Refer to http://www.bukisa.com/articles/263221_connected-components-using-opencv

Comment: I'm looking for an event motion in view, not for a specific object but any object that crosses the FoV.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty good explanation in chapter 9 of the book ['Learning OpenCV: Computer Vision with the OpenCV Library'](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130). Depending on your scene (indoors/outdoors, lighting conditions etc) the learning stage of your algorithm consists of accumulating the difference between frames in a buffer, then filtering the result using morphology operations to cancel noise. Or, when basic cvAbsDiff detects spurious motion, you implement a little bit more complicated 'codebook' algorithm instead.

The source code is available on the OReilly's site.